# I want to know how to approach the cascode ce amplifier circuit and how to find input and output resistances

Tags: ltspice

when voltage gain is 100 and collector current is 1mA for cascode configuration [image]

Comment: Do you know how to draw the small-signal model? Because this is the first step you need to do if you want to find Rin and Rout.

Comment: I think, if one knows how a BJT works  we do not need a small-signal equivalent model at all.  However, this is true only when we neglect all secon-order and third-order effects which will cause errors in the same order (or less) as uncertainties/tolerances of the main contributing parameters (hie, hfe, hoe).

Comment: Please provide the values of all of the components in your schematic. Have you tried running a simulation?

Comment: @LvW it is almost impossible to explain why cascode stage raises the Rout by a huge amount without small signal model, I think.

Comment: I think, it would be a really bad situation if someone would not be able to explain WHY and HOW the output resistance of Q2 depends on Q1 and its properties. In such a case, one would not understand the meaning and structure of this model because it does not explain anything. It is only a visual representation of known relationships, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

You have to draw the small signal model to obtain a precise expression as below:

In your schematics, the two NPNs are the same. I assume equal rpi and ro.

Rout = ro + gm×ro×(ro||rpi) + (ro||rpi)

Of course you also have a Rc in parallel with it.

There is an easier way. As textbooks teach you, ground the input and apply a voltage Vx at the output to see the current Ix.

Rout = Vx/Ix.

Notice when doing this, an sine wave voltage source with some DC offset is needed to keep the transistor in active region.

Input impedance can be found in a similar way.